# How do you say you saved time in doing a task as well as saved your employer costs in terms of wages?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-usage, phrase-request, phrase-choice

I'd like to highlight in my resume that I was able to complete a 75-hour task in just 24 hours. I am not sure if my sentence below highlights two things:

1. I saved time.
2. I saved the employer money in terms of wages (the job was paid by hours).

> Wrote a program in XYZ that efficiently integrated and matched student information from multiple data sources, thereby saving the department over 51 hours of pay.

Are the following any better? If not, how should it be written?

> ... thereby saving the department over 51 hours of work and wages.
> ... thereby saving the department over 51 hours in time and wages.

---

*Additional request*: I'd like to know if this can be written in a way that is more impactful. Any suggestions? Here are the details:

So the work/problem I had to solve would have taken me around say 15 hours to do. I wrote a program on XYZ to speed up the task, which was not part of my job and my supervisor did not know that the process could be automated. It took me 7 hours to do the task; I saved 8 hours.

My supervisor immediately spread the word and referred me to another researcher in the department for my excellent work, who also needed similar support. I was also given a contract by this other researcher for a similar job. So in the new job, I used my code and finished similar tasks. I did a 60-hour job in 17 hours. So in total I saved 8+43=51 hours.

How can I highlight some of these details (e.g., saving time and money, and being given an additional contract) without it being too long or wordy?

Comment: Minor comment: from the fluency of your question, you sound like you are either a native English speaker, or if non-native then very fluent. Are you sure English Language _Learners_ is the best place to be asking, as opposed to [Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com), say? (In particular, see those tagged with [\[resume\]](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resume).)

Comment: @tkp Hey, thanks for the suggestion, but I think this is more of an "English language" problem than a WP one. I'll wait a bit and see if others can suggest some edit to my sentence.

Comment: Fair enough. So FWIW (and I'm the CEO of a technical firm and have had to read my fair share of resumes), one suggestion would be to express the saving as a percentage or ratio -- so, something like: "in just under 1/3 of the expected cost and time". A 51-hour saving might be impressive, but it might also be barely relevant (e.g. if the expected time was 2,051 hours). Stating the fractional saving is more impactful, not to mention being easier on the eyes and brain of tired, weary, and, yes, old and hard-bitten resume-reading employers. :-)

Comment: @tkp You're absolutely right. I like that idea of using a percentage/ratio. Maybe when you get time from your busy schedule, you could convert your comment to an answer - of course may be add a bit more here and there. I think I was looking for something like this: "expected cost and time".